# Showing the space of Hermitian matrices is isomorphic to the Euclidean space.

Tags: general-topology

The object in question is pretty straightforward: I would like to prove that the space of $N \times N$ Hermitian matrices, aka $\mathscr{H}_N$, is isomorphic to the Euclidean space, $\mathbb{R}^{N^2}$.

I know that every matrix in $\mathscr{H}_N$ can be described by $N^2$ real parameters: $x_{ii} = h_{ii} \in \mathbb{R}$ for the diagonal, and $x_{ij} = Re (h_{ij})$, $y_{ij} = Im (h_{ij})$, for above the diagonal, and obviously, the complex conjugation for below the diagonal.

I am reading this for research, and the author omits the proof of why $\mathscr{H}_N \cong \mathbb{R}^{N^2}$. I am just asking for a few more details here. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that for a Hermitian matrix $A$, the entries on and above the diagonal determine the rest of the entries since $a_{ji} = \overline{a_{ij}}$.  Since $a_{ii} = \overline{a_{ii}}$ we see the entries on the diagonal must be real.  There are $N$ diagonal entries, so this contributes $N$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$.

There are $1 + 2 + \cdots + (N-1) = \frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ entries strictly above the diagonal.  These entries can be complex, so this contributes $\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ copies of $\mathbb{C}$.  Since $\mathbb{C}^m \cong \mathbb{R}^{2m}$, then $\mathbb{C}^\frac{N(N-1)}{2} \cong \mathbb{R}^{N(N-1)}$.  Thus we see the space of $N \times N$ Hermitian matrices is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^N \oplus \mathbb{R}^{N^2 - N} \cong \mathbb{R}^{N^2}$.